# More than one transformer in a single entity using DataImportHandler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am using DataImportHandler for indexing data in Solr.

I am retrieving data from three columns from AUTO table in database where two columns namely TOPIC and PARTS have data of type 'CLOB' and column DATE has oracle timestamp which holds created date.

The problem is in my data-config file where I need to transform the clob data to string and also date to the UTC that Solr uses.

So I need two transformers i.e ClobTransformer and DateFormatTransformer.

I am wondering how will I use both the transformers in single entity.

here is my data-config file

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="ds1" type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="....."
    user="....."
    password="...."/>
    <document name="doc">
        <entity name="ent" 
                query="Select 
                            auto.ID,
                            auto.Topic as Topic,
                            auto.Parts as Parts,
                            to_date(to_char(auto.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS Date,
                        From auto 
                        order by auto.Date DESC" 
                dataSource="ds1" transformer="DateFormatTransformer">
            <field column="ID" name="id"/>
            <field column="TOPIC" name="topic" clob="true"/>
            <field column="PARTS" name="parts" clob="true"/>
            <field column="DATE" name="date" xpath="/RDF/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" locale="en"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Above I have used only DateFormatTransformer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I came to know how its done. Just specifying the particular transformers using commas in the 'transformer' section of the  tag like this:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="ds1" type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="....."
    user="....."
    password="...."/>
    <document name="doc">
        <entity name="ent" 
                query="Select 
                            auto.ID,
                            auto.Topic as Topic,
                            auto.Parts as Parts,
                            to_date(to_char(auto.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS Date,
                        From auto 
                        order by auto.Date DESC" 
                dataSource="ds1" transformer="ClobTransformer,DateFormatTransformer">
            <field column="ID" name="id"/>
            <field column="TOPIC" name="topic" clob="true"/>
            <field column="PARTS" name="parts" clob="true"/>
            <field column="DATE" name="date" xpath="/RDF/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" locale="en"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I have used two transformers, `transformer="ClobTransformer,DateFormatTransformer"`